# Campos de texto (textarea, text, etc) não mostram o ponteiro do mouse e nem o texto digitado

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Boa noite, pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo um ambiente para criação de questionários e, no momento de coletar dados sobre as perguntas, tenho um formulário para cada tipo de pergunta, que é selecionado por um "dropdown-menu". Acontece que os campos de texto destes formulários estão "errados" de alguma forma. O ponteiro do mouse não aparece depois da seleção do campo (clique no campo de texto). O texto digitado também não aparece.

Este problema só ocorre nos campos que estão dentro do esquema de abas, o campo de ler o título do questionário está sem problemas, portanto, imagino que possa ser alguma coisa relacionada a estas abas e/ou a seleção "dropdown-menu".

Segue o projeto no codepen:
https://codepen.io/AmygdalaClicker/pen/ZavgBq

Provavelmente tem muita coisa incompleta e, se tratando da parte de controle, talvez até coisas erradas, portanto, peço que ignorem por enquanto. Gostaria somente de resolver o problema dos campos de texto.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no `color:#fff;` da classe:

```
.tab-content{
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px
}
```

Como está com estilo de cor de texto branca (`#fff`), o texto fica ilegível nos `textarea` e nos `input` por terem fundo branco. Aplique uma cor a esses elementos adicionando o código ao CSS:

```
textarea, input{
  color: #000; /* neste caso, cor preta */
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! 

Só ocorreu um outro problema. Realmente o erro parece ser este, adicionei o código ao CSS no codepen e os campos ficaram normais agora. Entretanto, adicionei o código ao meu projeto aqui e a alteração não teve efeito. Sabe o que pode ter ocorrido?


Grato!

Comment: Consegui aqui, mano. Foi só limpar o cache do navegador. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado! Estava a um tempo neste problema.

Comment: @AcreanoDingo-Dingo É isso mesmo. O navegador é chato com arquivos css que guarda no cache. As vezes tenho esse problema tb.